# Ayuda con fileupload en java ee 7 xhtml, obtener n archivos subidos

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

espero me puedan ayudar con esto.

Estoy con una app web en java ee 7 primefaces como la vista y los Beans correspondientes.

Lo que deseo es lo siguiente:

Mediante la selección de una categoría en particular, se generan requisitos de forma dinámica y a lado de ellos, se añade un FileUpload, es decir que cada requisito debe subirse un archivo.
La vista me renderiza correctamente cada requisito con su FileUpload, lo que deseo hacer es guardar esos archivos que se suben con el id del requisito correspondiente.

Primefaces me brinda el fileupload básico [ver aquí codigo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml), pero al momento de enviar el id del requisito, mediante el submit, no recibo en el bean correspondiente.

Mientras que con este fileupload de primefaces mismo [ver aquí](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml), no puedo enviar el parámetro correspondiente, no se como podría sobreescribir ese método (el que tiene el fileuploadevent) para enviar ahí mismo el id del requisito.

Espero me puedan ayudar...

Answer (score 0):

Se está utilizando un formulario para enviar la información al servidor, por lo que puede adjuntar más componentes y asignárselos a una propiedad en su managed bean:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:fileUpload value="#{bean.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/>

    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.id}" />

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{fileUploadView.upload}" disabled="true" />
</h:form>
```

Si la información se genera de forma dinámica, supongo que puede estar utilizando *Js* para éste procedimiento y con js puede asignarle el `id` que le corresponde a cada nuevo componente de `fileUpload` ...